# Are browser-width and screen resolution the same?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am creating a responsive website/hybrid app and im starting to discover lot of new information regarding CSS3.

While going through media-queries, i found that we can detect the so many properties of browser as follows :

```
min-device-width
max-device-width
min-device-height
max-device-height
orientation:portrait
orientation:landscape
-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio
-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio
```

and many more...

So my question is :

**1. Is the screen resolution the same as the device-width obtained..?**

**2. If not, Can i target the browser resolution using css3?**

Thanks

Roy

Answer (score 0):

> **device-width**
>   Describes the width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).
>
> **width**
>   The width media feature describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page box on a printer).

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)